# Resource Picture No longer loading

Tags: c#, wpf, embedded-resource

I have a picture in the resources that I have been loading using the following code:

```
var path = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/DocumentHandlingTouch;component/Resources/pdf.jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
```

My computer crashed in between builds and now it doesn;t load that picture onto the canvas at all any more.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have set the build action of the image files to 'Resource' in your project.

```
var pdfimage = new Image();
BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
src.BeginInit();
src.UriSource = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/DocumentHandlingTouch;component/Resources/pdf.jpg", UriKind.Absolute); 
src.EndInit();
pdfimage.Source = src;
```

Comment: I have it set to resource, but it still wont go. There is another image in the resources, and that one works. no clue

Comment: if you just change the image name in above Uri, then the new image is getting displayed?